# How to get changed time using cypress?

Tags: time, cypress

In the test ,I have to change a comment and save
In the edit history I can see who changed what and the time when it is changed.
I want to verify the time it was changed.

Two things to verify

1. Get the current time when I change the comment.
2. Get the time from the edit history and it should match to the time in the step 1.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is the [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Now) command,

Essentially, `cy.clock()` freezes the time in the app so you don't get any variation due to fast/slow processing.

Adapted from the example in the docs:

```js
const now = new Date(2021, 3, 14) // month is 0-indexed

cy.clock(now)        // use a specific date for testing purposes

// change the comment

cy.get('#comment').should('have.value', '04/14/2021')
```